# R: object not found but getAnywhere says it exists

Tags: r

So I'm trying to use the `create16dayts` function which is supposed to be part of the `bfast` package but R can't find it. When I call `getAnywhere`, it says it's in the `bfast` namespace, so I expect that I can access it after calling `library(bfast)` but that's not the case. (The expected behavior of the MWE below is that `create16dayts()` throws an error complaining about missing arguments.)

```
> getAnywhere(create16dayts)
A single object matching ‘create16dayts’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:bfast
with value

function (data, dates) 
{
    z <- zoo(data, dates)
    yr <- as.numeric(format(time(z), "%Y"))
    jul <- as.numeric(format(time(z), "%j"))
    delta <- min(unlist(tapply(jul, yr, diff)))
    zz <- aggregate(z, yr + (jul - 1)/delta/23)
    (tso <- as.ts(zz))
    return(tso)
}
<environment: namespace:bfast>
> library(bfast)
> create16dayts()
Error: could not find function "create16dayts"
> create16dayts
Error: object 'create16dayts' not found
```

Why can't I use the `create16dayts` function?

I've already tried re-installing `bfast` with `install.packages("bfast", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the function isn't exported from the package. You can get to un-exported functions with the triple colon

```
bfast:::create16dayts
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. It is really strange though as this function is listed on the main help page, i.e. on `help(bfast)`.

Comment: It is odd. Perhaps you should contact the package authors to fix the problem.

Comment: I'm getting really confused now. I just tried to access the `modisraster` object in the `bfast` package and even `getAnywhere` can't find it. I'm fairly confident that I've used that object a couple weeks ago and had no problems at all. Now I'm thinking again that there might be a problem with the installation.